# Wordpress enabling Curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Note: I'm on Windows 10.

Hello,

I have a problem enabling curl and have tried almost everything. Enabling it at C:\PHP\php.ini. I've included C:\PHP, C:\PHP\ext, C:\apache24\bin, C:\Windows\system32 at environmental variables so it has access to the files. But still when i tried phpinfo() function and searching for curl it is there but next to it is only the author it is not saying enabled. I've tried get_loaded_extensions() function and i don't see curl there. If someone can help will be great.

Comment: Have you restarted the PHP and/or Apache process?

Comment: What does phpinfo tell you, which configuration file(s) were actually used?

Comment: Yes, everytime when i changed something i restarted the Apache.

Comment: @CBroe it shows on Loaded configuration file that it is using C:\PHP\php.ini